# Reactjs npm ERR! code1

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image]

I've already uninstall -g create-react-app but still can not create my project

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Try to [clear npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/folders#cache) first. To force it you can run `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: `D:\Test-React>npm cache clean --force`
```npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Your image shows up fine in the first post.

You should try using `npx create-react-app my-test`. I dont know why but this worked for me when npm goes haywire when creating a react app.

Comment: Yes I did but.. still can not i dont know can u  see my cmd image

Comment: Does the problem persists?

Comment: https://www.picz.in.th/image/oNDV9S <<< I dont know how to add image Sorry T^T

Comment: Your images are uploaded fine. btw, try this one `npx create-react-app@latest my-test --use-npm`

Comment: https://www.picz.in.th/image/oNAj71 <<< Thank you so much but still error T.T

Comment: @mind-chn Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please also see [why should I not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Interesting. Run cmd in admin mode and try `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, and then `npm install create-react-app`. Next `npx create-react-app my-test`

Please refer to the page "how to ask" @DaveNewton stated.

Comment: Yeahhh~ I can do it!!!! , thank you very much. I really want to thank you for your help. I will delete this post and go learn How to Ask first. Next time I will create the correct post. Sorry for my first post. It is very sudden

Comment: In stack overflow, you can thank a member when then post a useful answer by upvoting that answer. If you found an answer as the correct one, you should accept that answer by clicking the "Tick" mark. And I suggest you should edit this question to a better one instead of deleting it. Kudos @mind-chn. Btw, did the last suggestion worked fine?